# Razorpay checkout window is not opening in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, razorpay

Because of some reasons instead of using razorpay plugins available in WordPress, I am writing my own plugin where I have created a form and after submit I want to redirect it to the Razorpay checkout window. I have written following code for the same -

```
<html>
        <body>
        <form action="" method=POST>
                <label>Full Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
                <label>Mob Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="mobnum" id="mobnum"><br><br>
                <label>Address:</label>
                <input type="text" name="add" id="add"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
        </form>
        </body>
        <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
        <script>
                function myFunction() {
                        var name = document.getElementById("fname");
                        var mob = document.getElementById("mobnum");
                        var add = document.getElementById("add");
                        var options = {
                            "key": "*********",
                            "data-amount": "100", // 2000 paise = INR 20
                            "data-currency": "INR",
                            "data-id": "<?php echo 'OID'.rand(10,100).'END';?>",
                            "data-name": "Plugin Test",
                            "data-description": "Plugin Testing Training",
                            "handler": function (response){

                                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                            },
                            "prefill": {
                                "name": "XYZ",
                                "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
                            },
                            "theme": {
                                "color": "#F37254"
                            }
                        };
                        var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
                        rzp1.open();
                    }
        </script>
        </html>
```

But here the problem is razorpay checkout window is not opening and its throwing an error as below -

```
"serviceworker" must be a dictionary in your web app manifest.
```

Can anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved with the help of jQuery. I have added jQuery script and made following changes in code -

```
<html>
        <body>
        <form action="" method=POST>
                <label>Full Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
                <label>Mob Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="mobnum" id="mobnum"><br><br>
                <label>Address:</label>
                <input type="text" name="add" id="add"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        </body>
        <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
        <script src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                jQuery('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var name = document.getElementById("fname");
                        var mob = document.getElementById("mobnum");
                        var add = document.getElementById("add");
                        var options = {
                            "key": "*********",
                            "data-amount": "100", // 2000 paise = INR 20
                            "data-currency": "INR",
                            "data-id": "<?php echo 'OID'.rand(10,100).'END';?>",
                            "data-name": "Plugin Test",
                            "data-description": "Plugin Testing Training",
                            "handler": function (response){

                                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                            },
                            "prefill": {
                                "name": "XYZ",
                                "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
                            },
                            "theme": {
                                "color": "#F37254"
                            }
                        };
                        var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
                        rzp1.open();
                    });
        </script>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here with the form 'POST'.

So maybe u can remove the POST and call  myFunction() onclick.

example - `onClick = " myFunction()"`

This

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the way you suggested but its not working.

Comment: In case Razorpay plugin is not working, please raise a request here  - https://razorpay.com/support/